# After finishing the updates, if the option "restart later" is chosen, is it okay if it's just shutdown?

Tags: updates, shutdown, restart

or is it necessary to remember to only restart the system?
If you shut down and later start the system, is it the same as restarting it?

Comment: It is okay to shut down and then start it again. Source: my own experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is totally no problem in doing that. Your computer will just apply the update the next time you boot up.

Answer (score 1):

restart and "shut down - boot up" actually does the same things as far as updates are concerned

so you can do any of those